# Windows 8 with slow internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-8, performance

I upgraded a laptop from Windos 7 to Windows 8.

Now there are some problems, but the most annoying is the following network issue:

It is just slow and sometimes stops working.

With Windows 7 I had 1-2 MByte/s

With Windows 8 I have 14 kBit/s-20 kByte (Internet Explorer or Comodo Dragon download - also Taskmanager jumps between 0 and 1.2 Mbit/s)

The store sometimes says "disconnected"

There are no newer network drivers (BroadCom 802.11n).

I tried to turn of the firewall - no change

With a far to much clicks i turned of Defender - no change

FIPS turned off/on - no change

What else could it be, or with which steps could the issue be  I'm just a little bit before restoring Windows 7 again ...

Comment: Have you tried another browser?  Are there any other users on the network using Windows 7 who could verify they are still getting 1.2MB?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the manufacturer website of your Motherboard and check for new updates of any drivers, especially the network related ones.

See if they have released any new versions specific to Windows 8.

Alternatively, in windows 8 when You are opening any Metro based application, make sure that you close it after your done or else it will suck up your bandwidth.

Comment: Minimized Metro applications are suspended they can't use bandwidth.

Comment: as stated above : "here are no newer network drivers (BroadCom 802.11n)." It's a laptop - and no new driver (and you will barely find mainboard drivers for laptops instead the ones from manufacturer...). The problem exists also, if only one non Metro application (the browser) is started. For started application (independed wether it is IE, Dragon, even tried it with steam), the  taskmanager shows above behaviour. I also foundd some other sides on the web were people have the problem, but non of the solutions seems to help anybody. So i search for a way to dig deeper in the problem.